# Netbeans and Xdebug

Tags: php

I have netbeans 7.3 installed, php 5.4.7 and xdebug via xampp configured correctly.

When I try to start a debugging session on my index.html file that contains the form I am submitting to my php file the debugger never connects(waiting to connect). However, if I start the debugger on the php file it runs but, of course, it has no values from the form on the index page?

Here are my php.ini settings:

```
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Also, if I use debug project, it loads in my browser with the debug session but does not stop at any of my breakpoints within the IDE

Answer (score 0):

i can't say exaclly solution, but according to my experiences, you should try following steps

1. Dowload correct version of xdebug from [xdebug custom download](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php)
   and paste your phpinfo() output
2. restart netbeans and xammp
3. if hope you have [xdebug] before your these ini settings, i have followings in my php ini

   ; XDEBUG Extension

   zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.5/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc6.dll"

   [xdebug]
   xdebug.remote_enable=on
   xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
   xdebug.collect_params=0
   xdebug.remote_host=localhost
   xdebug.remote_port=9000

i am using netbeans 7.3, php 5.3.5

Answer (score 0):

i use xampp 1.8.1(php 5.4.7) and netbeans ide 7.3

this is my php.ini config, i have some warnings when apache starts but i can debug nicely.

also be sure to config the port of debug at netbeans tools,php,debbug,port 9000

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0;
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1;
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0 ;
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="C:\xampp\tmp" ;
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s" ;
xdebug.remote_enable = 1;
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp" ;
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1";
xdebug.remote_port = 9000;
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp";
```